# new Date(2014,1,1) converts to 1th february with momentJS

Tags: javascript, momentjs

Why does this declaration result in a momentJS object with Date 1th February 2014 ???

```
var startDate = moment(new Date(2014, 1, 1));
```

Comment: Has nothing to do with `momentjs`. [MDN Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) *"**month:**
    Integer value representing the month, beginning with 0 for January to 11 for December."*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because the second argument is 0-11 in the `Date` object. (1 being Feb). Its not a MomentJS issue.

Change to `new Date(2014, 0, 1)`

Answer (score 0):

because the month is 0 based. you would do

```
var startDate = moment(new Date(2014, 0, 1));
```

for jan.